# Apple Music "Content not authorized" error

Tags: iphone, network, music, apple-music

Yesterday I started my free trial of Apple Music and downloaded about 200 songs on my iPhone through Wi-Fi and it worked fine (with Wi-Fi turned on). Today I went for a walk and I could not play the downloaded music offline. Once I turn off both Wi-Fi and Cellular network I get an error: “Cannot Open: This content is not authorized”. Neither of songs downloaded to the phone works. However, if I turn my Wi-Fi back on, everything works perfectly fine. Does anyone know how to deal with it?

Answer (score 2):

In Settings > Music, is the "iCloud Music Library" toggled on? I would start with checking that first.
If it's already the case, I would recommend signing out and back in with your Apple ID in Settings > iTunes & App Stores.

I'm subscribed to Apple Music, and had a similar issue recently after changing phones. Something wrong with DRM I assume, so authenticating again should be enough to solve it.

Comment: "iCloud Library" is always toggled on while I am struggling with the problem. Also I have tried reauthentification several times. That does not help. Once I turn off Wi-Fi it plays at most three songs offline and then nothing happens. You have said that you had similar issue. Did authenticating again help you?

Comment: Sorry that didn't help. Yes, after authenticating again, it's been working trouble-free ever since...

Answer (score 0):

By the way, the problem have been solved. The last thing I did was downloading U2 - Songs of Innocence Album to my phone. It was purchased from iTunes several years ago. Probably that helped with authenting again as Léopold suggested.